# How to block until a BlockingQueue is empty?

Tags: java, concurrency, blockingqueue

I'm looking for a way to block until a `BlockingQueue` is empty.

I know that, in a multithreaded environment, as long as there are producers putting items into the `BlockingQueue`, there can be situations in which the queue becomes empty and a few nanoseconds later it is full of items.

But, if there's only *one* producer, then it may want to wait (and block) until the queue is empty after it has stopped putting items into the queue.

Java/Pseudocode:

```
// Producer code
BlockingQueue queue = new BlockingQueue();

while (having some tasks to do) {
    queue.put(task);
}

queue.waitUntilEmpty(); // <-- how to do this?

print("Done");
```

Do you have any idea?

**EDIT**: I know that wrapping `BlockingQueue` and using an extra condition would do the trick, I'm just asking if there are some pre-made solutions and/or better alternatives.

Comment: Clearly you could call `peek` until it returns `null`. What is it about blocking that makes this an unacceptable solution?

Comment: The answer to your edit, AFAIK, is no. Notice that, as I wrote in my answer, your use case is very peculiar... make sure you really need to do what you are asking for. You don't state why you **need** such behavior.

Comment: @JoãoFernandes: I don't strictly need it now, it's just out of curiosity. I like reading opinions on programming issues.

Comment: Now that is a good argument :) lets wait for more answers to see if someone knows something that we are not aware of.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A simple solution using `wait()` and `notify()`:

```
// Producer:

// `sychronized` is necessary, otherwise `.notify` will not work
synchronized(queue) {
    while (!queue.isEmpty())
        queue.wait(); // wait for the queue to become empty
        // this is not a deadlock, because `.wait` will release the lock
    queue.put();
}

// Consumer:
synchronized(queue) {
    queue.get();
    if (queue.isEmpty())
        queue.notify(); // notify the producer
}
```

Comment: Hi @niculare, would this code cause a deadlock? Two code snippets lock on the same object `queue`, which prevents the producer and consumer do their works at the same time. So the queue may never have chance to be empty when producer is waiting for it to be.

Comment: @liuyaodong No, read the Javadoc for `Object.wait()`. It releases the lock until another thread calls `notify`. It even explicitly says that "The current thread must own this object's monitor".

Comment: How would this work? Say consumer runs first and is blocked on queue.get() because there's no item in the queue yet. Now the producer cannot produce because it cannot obtain the lock.

Comment: `BlockingQueue` does not have `get` method. Do you mean `poll` or `take`?

Comment: I meant `take`, as `poll` won't have any effect in this context

Comment: I added some comments, it looks like a deadlock but it is not and works perfectly. Also the type of the queue is not important.

Comment: @hankduan maybe need producer run first

Comment: is the `queue.put()`  should in the while block?

Answer (score 8):

I understand you could already have bunch of threads actively polling or taking the queue but I still feel not quite right about your flow/design.

The queue becomes empty doesn't mean the previously added tasks are finished, somes of the items could take ages to process, so it is not too useful to check for empty.

So what you should do is forget about the `BlockingQueue`, you can use it as any other collections. Translate the items into a `Collections` of `Callable` and make use of the `ExecutorService.invokeAll()`.

```
    Collection<Item> queue = ...
    Collection<Callable<Result>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Result>>();

    for (Item item : queue) {
        tasks.add(new Callable<Result>() {

            @Override
            public Result call() throws Exception {
                // process the item ...

                return result;
            }
        });
    }

    // look at the results, add timeout for invokeAll if necessary
    List<Future<Result>> results = executorService.invokeAll(tasks);

    // done
```

This approach will give you full control of how long your producer could wait and proper exception handling.

Answer (score 4):

It's not quite what you want to do, but using a `SynchronousQueue` would have a very similar effect as your Java/Pseudocode, namely the producer blocking until all of the data has been retrieved by some consumer.

Only difference being the producer blocking on each put until a consumer comes to retrieve the data, instead of only once at the end. Not sure if that would make a difference in your case. I'd expect it to only make a noticeable difference, if the task performed by the producer is somewhat expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Your use case should be quite special because most typically you would only want to block the producer when the queue is full, but not wait until it is empty.

Anyway, this is doable. I believe that spinning until `isEmpty` returns true is not THAT inefficient because the producer will be locally spinning, i.e., will be accessing its own cache, not banging the bus. It will however be consume CPU time as the thread remains schedulable. But local spinning is definitely the easier way. Otherwise I see two options:

1. Using `wait` + `notify` like @niculare suggested
2. Somehow make the first consumer that notices the queue empty to notify the producer in a lock-free way; this will be slower but degrade "more" gracefully

Answer (score 1):

The answer @niculare gave seems OK but check out the comment of @hankduan.

I saw this question when searching for the solution of a similar problem.
At the end, I more or less rewrote `LinkedBlockingQueue`.
It has a subset of its methods and does not implement `Collection` or `Iterable`.
It manages multiple producers and consumers.
For me it works.

```
/**********************************************************************************************************************
 * Import specifications
 *********************************************************************************************************************/
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

/**********************************************************************************************************************
 * This class implements a completely reentrant FIFO.
 *********************************************************************************************************************/
public class BlockingFIFO<E>
{
  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * The constructor creates an empty FIFO with a capacity of {@link Integer#MAX_VALUE}.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  public BlockingFIFO()
  {
    // -----------------
    // Initialize object
    // -----------------
    this(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

  } // constructor

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * The constructor creates an empty FIFO with the specified capacity.
   *
   * @param capacity_ipar The maximum number of elements the FIFO may contain.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  public BlockingFIFO(int capacity_ipar)
  {
    // ---------------------
    // Initialize attributes
    // ---------------------
    lock_attr = new ReentrantLock();
    not_empty_attr = lock_attr.newCondition();
    not_full_attr = lock_attr.newCondition();
    head_attr = null;
    tail_attr = null;
    capacity_attr = capacity_ipar;
    size_attr = 0;

  } // constructor

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method removes all of the elements from the FIFO.
   *
   * @return The number of elements in the FIFO before it was cleared.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  public int clear()
  {
    // -----------------
    // Initialize result
    // -----------------
    int result;
    result = 0;

    // ----------
    // Clear FIFO
    // ----------
    lock_attr.lock();
    try
    {
      result = size_attr;
      head_attr = null;
      tail_attr = null;
      size_attr = 0;
      not_full_attr.signalAll();
    }
    finally
    {
      lock_attr.unlock();
    }

    // ----
    // Done
    // ----
    return (result);

  } // clear

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method returns the number of elements in the FIFO.
   *
   * @return The number of elements in the FIFO.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  public int size()
  {
    // -----------
    // Return size
    // -----------
    lock_attr.lock();
    try
    {
      return (size_attr);
    }
    finally
    {
      lock_attr.unlock();
    }

  } // size

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method returns the number of additional elements that the FIFO can ideally accept without blocking.
   *
   * @return The remaining capacity the FIFO.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  public int remainingCapacity()
  {
    // -------------------------
    // Return remaining capacity
    // -------------------------
    lock_attr.lock();
    try
    {
      return (capacity_attr - size_attr);
    }
    finally
    {
      lock_attr.unlock();
    }

  } // remainingCapacity

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method waits for the FIFO to become empty.
   *
   * @throws InterruptedException Thrown when the current thread got interrupted while waiting for the FIFO to become
   *                              empty.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  public void waitEmpty()
    throws InterruptedException
  {
    // -----------------------------
    // Wait for FIFO to become empty
    // -----------------------------
    lock_attr.lock();
    try
    {
      while (size_attr > 0)
        not_full_attr.await();
    }
    finally
    {
      lock_attr.unlock();
    }

  } // waitEmpty

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method waits at most the specified time for the FIFO to become empty.
   * <br>It returns <code>true</code> if the FIFO is empty and <code>false</code> otherwise.
   *
   * @param  timeout_ipar         The maximum number of milliseconds to wait for the FIFO to become empty.
   * @return                      True if and only if the FIFO is empty.
   * @throws InterruptedException Thrown when the current thread got interrupted while waiting for the FIFO to become
   *                              empty.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  public boolean waitEmpty(long timeout_ipar)
    throws InterruptedException
  {
    // ------------------
    // Determine deadline
    // ------------------
    Date deadline;
    deadline = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout_ipar);

    // -----------------------------
    // Wait for FIFO to become empty
    // -----------------------------
    lock_attr.lock();
    try
    {
      while (size_attr > 0)
      {
        if (!not_full_attr.awaitUntil(deadline))
          return (false);
      }
      return (true);
    }
    finally
    {
      lock_attr.unlock();
    }

  } // waitEmpty

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method waits at most the specified time for the FIFO to become empty.
   * <br>It returns <code>true</code> if the FIFO is empty and <code>false</code> otherwise.
   *
   * @param  timeout_ipar         The maximum time to wait for the FIFO to become empty.
   * @param  unit_ipar            The unit of the specified timeout.
   * @return                      True if and only if the FIFO is empty.
   * @throws InterruptedException Thrown when the current thread got interrupted while waiting for the FIFO to become
   *                              empty.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  public boolean waitEmpty(long    timeout_ipar,
                           TimeUnit unit_ipar)
    throws InterruptedException
  {
    // -----------------------------
    // Wait for FIFO to become empty
    // -----------------------------
    return (waitEmpty(unit_ipar.toMillis(timeout_ipar)));

  } // waitEmpty

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method adds the specified element at the end of the FIFO if it is possible to do so immediately without
   * exceeding the queue's capacity.
   * <br>It returns <code>true</code> upon success and <code>false</code> if this queue is full.
   *
   * @param  element_ipar The element to add to the FIFO.
   * @return              True if and only if the element was added to the FIFO.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  public boolean offer(E element_ipar)
  {
    // ----------------------
    // Try to add the element
    // ----------------------
    lock_attr.lock();
    try
    {
      if (capacity_attr > size_attr)
      {
        push(element_ipar);
        return (true);
      }
      else
        return (false);
    }
    finally
    {
      lock_attr.unlock();
    }

  } // offer

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method adds the specified element at the end of the FIFO, waiting if necessary up to the specified wait time
   * for space to become available.
   * <br>It returns <code>true</code> upon success and <code>false</code> if this queue is full.
   *
   * @param  element_ipar         The element to add to the FIFO.
   * @param  timeout_ipar         The maximum number of milliseconds to wait for space to become available.
   * @return                      True if and only if the element was added to the FIFO.
   * @throws InterruptedException Thrown when the current thread got interrupted while waiting for space to become
   *                              available.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  public boolean offer(E    element_ipar,
                       long timeout_ipar)
    throws InterruptedException
  {
    // ------------------
    // Determine deadline
    // ------------------
    Date deadline;
    deadline = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout_ipar);

    // ----------------------
    // Try to add the element
    // ----------------------
    lock_attr.lock();
    try
    {
      while (size_attr == capacity_attr)
      {
        if (!not_full_attr.awaitUntil(deadline))
          return (false);
      }
      push(element_ipar);
      return (true);
    }
    finally
    {
      lock_attr.unlock();
    }

  } // offer

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method adds the specified element at the end of the FIFO, waiting if necessary up to the specified wait time
   * for space to become available.
   * <br>It returns <code>true</code> upon success and <code>false</code> if this queue is full.
   *
   * @param  element_ipar         The element to add to the FIFO.
   * @param  timeout_ipar         The maximum time to wait for space to become available.
   * @param  unit_ipar            The unit of the specified timeout.
   * @return                      True if and only if the element was added to the FIFO.
   * @throws InterruptedException Thrown when the current thread got interrupted while waiting for space to become
   *                              available.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  public boolean offer(E        element_ipar,
                       long     timeout_ipar,
                       TimeUnit unit_ipar)
    throws InterruptedException
  {
    // ----------------------------
    // Try to add specified element
    // ----------------------------
    return (offer(element_ipar, unit_ipar.toMillis(timeout_ipar)));

  } // offer

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method adds the specified element at the end of the FIFO, waiting if necessary for space to become available.
   *
   * @throws InterruptedException Thrown when the current thread got interrupted while waiting for space to become
   *                              available.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  public void put(E element_ipar)
    throws InterruptedException
  {
    // ----------------------
    // Try to add the element
    // ----------------------
    lock_attr.lock();
    try
    {
      while (size_attr == capacity_attr)
        not_full_attr.await();
      push(element_ipar);
    }
    finally
    {
      lock_attr.unlock();
    }

  } // put

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method retrieves, but does not remove, the head of the FIFO, or returns <code>null</code> if the FIFO is
   * empty.
   *
   * @return The head of the FIFO, or <code>null</code> if the FIFO is empty.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  public E peek()
  {
    // --------------------
    // Return first element
    // --------------------
    lock_attr.lock();
    try
    {
      if (size_attr == 0)
        return (null);
      else
        return (head_attr.contents);
    }
    finally
    {
      lock_attr.unlock();
    }

  } // peek

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method retrieves and removes the head of the FIFO, or returns <code>null</code> if the FIFO is
   * empty.
   *
   * @return The head of the FIFO, or <code>null</code> if the FIFO is empty.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  public E poll()
  {
    // --------------------
    // Return first element
    // --------------------
    lock_attr.lock();
    try
    {
      if (size_attr == 0)
        return (null);
      else
        return (pop());
    }
    finally
    {
      lock_attr.unlock();
    }

  } // poll

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method retrieves and removes the head of the FIFO, waiting up to the specified wait time if necessary for an
   * element to become available.
   * <br>It returns <code>null</code> if the specified waiting time elapses before an element is available.
   *
   * @param  timeout_ipar         The maximum number of milliseconds to wait for an element to become available.
   * @return                      The head of the FIFO, or <code>null</code> if the specified waiting time elapses
   *                              before an element is available.
   * @throws InterruptedException Thrown when the current thread got interrupted while waiting for an element to become
   *                              available.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  public E poll(long timeout_ipar)
    throws InterruptedException
  {
    // ------------------
    // Determine deadline
    // ------------------
    Date deadline;
    deadline = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout_ipar);

    // --------------------
    // Return first element
    // --------------------
    lock_attr.lock();
    try
    {
      while (size_attr == 0)
      {
        if (!not_empty_attr.awaitUntil(deadline))
          return (null);
      }
      return (pop());
    }
    finally
    {
      lock_attr.unlock();
    }

  } // poll

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method retrieves and removes the head of the FIFO, waiting up to the specified wait time if necessary for an
   * element to become available.
   * <br>It returns <code>null</code> if the specified waiting time elapses before an element is available.
   *
   * @param  timeout_ipar         The maximum time to wait for an element to become available.
   * @param  unit_ipar            The unit of the specified timeout.
   * @return                      The head of the FIFO, or <code>null</code> if the specified waiting time elapses
   *                              before an element is available.
   * @throws InterruptedException Thrown when the current thread got interrupted while waiting for an element to become
   *                              available.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  public E poll(long     timeout_ipar,
                TimeUnit unit_ipar)
    throws InterruptedException
  {
    // ------------------------
    // Try to get first element
    // ------------------------
    return (poll(unit_ipar.toMillis(timeout_ipar)));

  } // poll

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method retrieves and removes the head of the FIFO, waiting if necessary for an element to become available.
   *
   * @return                      The head of the FIFO.
   * @throws InterruptedException Thrown when the current thread got interrupted while waiting for space to become
   *                              available.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  public E take()
    throws InterruptedException
  {
    // ---------------------------
    // Try to return first element
    // ---------------------------
    lock_attr.lock();
    try
    {
      while (size_attr == 0)
        not_empty_attr.await();
      return (pop());
    }
    finally
    {
      lock_attr.unlock();
    }

  } // take

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This class implements as node within the FIFO.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  private class Node
  {
    E    contents;
    Node next;

  } // class Node

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method adds the specified element to the end of the FIFO.
   * <br>It sends a signal to all threads waiting for the FIFO to contain something.
   * <br>The caller should have locked the object and have made sure the list is not full.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  private void push(E element_ipar)
  {
    // -----------
    // Create node
    // -----------
    Node node;
    node = new Node();
    node.contents = element_ipar;
    node.next = null;

    // --------------
    // Add to the end
    // --------------
    if (head_attr == null)
      head_attr = node;
    else
      tail_attr.next = node;
    tail_attr = node;

    // ----------------------
    // We got another element
    // ----------------------
    size_attr++;
    not_empty_attr.signalAll();

  } // push

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method removes the first element from the FIFO and returns it.
   * <br>It sends a signal to all threads waiting for the FIFO to have space available.
   * <br>The caller should have locked the object and have made sure the list is not empty.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  private E pop()
  {
    // ------------
    // Isolate node
    // ------------
    Node node;
    node = head_attr;
    head_attr = node.next;
    if (head_attr == null)
      tail_attr = null;

    // --------------------------
    // We removed another element
    // --------------------------
    size_attr--;
    not_full_attr.signalAll();

    // ----
    // Done
    // ----
    return (node.contents);

  } // pop

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This attribute represents the lock on the FIFO.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  private Lock lock_attr;

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This attribute represents the condition of the FIFO not being empty.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  private Condition not_empty_attr;

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This attribute represents the condition of the FIFO not being full.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  private Condition not_full_attr;

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This attribute represents the first element of the FIFO.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  private Node head_attr;

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This attribute represents the last element of the FIFO.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  private Node tail_attr;

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This attribute represents the capacity of the FIFO.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  private int capacity_attr;

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This attribute represents the size of the FIFO.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  private int size_attr;

} // class BlockingFIFO
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html),
BlockingQueue can be blocked on "Remove" by methods: `take()` or `poll(time, unit)` instead of `poll()`